# Is renting with AirBnB in Abu- Dhabi safe?

Tags: airbnb, abu-dhabi

Is renting in Abu Dhabi trough AirBnB safe for a family (i.e. renters)?

I am mostly concerned if ladies can walk freely (unlike Saudia), and also is it safe for ladies travelling alone?

Comment: Do you have a particular concern?

Comment: I am coming with my family. I have three main concerns, is it safe for ladies + is it strict like in Saudia where ladies cannot go outside alone + snatching of luggage etc.

Comment: Not a lady myself, but UAE looks exceptionally safe for women and shopping malls are full of them, including many in Western clothes. There are signs advising modest clothing in malls, but some ignore them. AirBnB I think always requires some caution if you rent a room inside a stranger's home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use of AirBnB in UAE is both safe and common.

> I am mostly concerned if ladies can walk freely (unlike Saudia)

This question has nothing to do with AirBnB and is a separate question in its own right, however just for the sake of completeness: Yes, ladies can and do walk freely in the tourist/shopping areas  in the UAE.